# how to get value from the previous hidden input from a span tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to get value from a hidden input previous to a span tag using jQuery

```
    <div>
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $activeTimeID; ?>" class="activeTimeId"
  name="activeTimeID<?php echo $j;?>[]" />
     <span class="closeTime">close</span>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.closeTime').prev('input').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

use [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get the previous element - passing in input:hidden as the selector - so it will only look for hidden inputs

```
$('span.closeTime').prev('input:hidden').val()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`prev([selector])`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```
var val = $('span').prev('input[type="hidden"]').val();
```

This will find span and select immediately preceding sibling which is `input[type="hidden"]`